# Combining Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science

Is it possible to combine multiple types of data through a neural network and in return output a particular datatype?

For example, can I input an image and some metadata about that image, then the algorithm will output a number.

I'm thinking along the lines of stitching a CNN and ANN together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the end, neural networks always take numbers/floats and return floats, so it is principal possible, if you are able to convert the data. But don`t expect the network to automatically recognize the differences in your data by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Actually, that is pretty straightforward.
Commonly, what happens in image classification (for example) is that a so-called feature map (generated by the last convolutional layer in this case) gets flattened. This flattened tensor is then fed through a feed-forward Neural Network (NN) to perform the classification task.

The easiest would be to simply add one layer to your network which [concatenates](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) two tensors ***a*** and ***b***, where ***a*** is the flattened output of the last convolutional layer and ***b*** is your meta-data (which is then ideally also a flattened tensor).

Afterwards, you simply feed the concatenated tensor (containing both the encoding of your image and the meta-data) through the feed-forward NN to perform the final classification (or generation of whatever the desired output is).